# jQuery .closest, .find and .toggleClass to vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I convert the following functions to a simple vanilla javascript equivalent?

```
   $(elem).closest(".container").find(".panel").toggleClass('active');
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: nothing because I don't understand plain JavaScript at all. It seems super verbose and complicated vs jQuery that's why I thought to post here to get help from someone that knows vanilla JS

Comment: Yes, `elem.closest(".container").querySelector(".panel").classList.toggle("active")` is *so* complicated...

Comment: I think once you have spent even a small amount of time working with modern, plain JavaScript, you will find it to be less verbose and far less complicated than JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With modern browser you can do it easily.

For closest [`element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

For find [`element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)

For classes [`element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Check link to know how you can do same thing with vanila js that can done by JQuery

[You might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
//    $(elem).closest(".container").find(".panel").toggleClass('active');

function doTheThing(el) {
  el.closest('.container').querySelector('.panel').classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='panel'>
    Panel
  </div>
  <div class='inner'>
    <button onclick='doTheThing(this)'>click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `parent = el.closest(".container")`